# Two providers in android manifest conflict

Tags: android, manifest, provider

I have two providers in manifest. It brings error depending what is written first.

```
     <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.boligchecker"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>

    <provider
        android:name=".data.BoligProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.boligchecker"
        android:exported="false"
        />
```

When android:name=".data.BoligProvider" is located **bottom**, the error bring FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1 error written the bottom of this text.

If android:name=".data.BoligProvider" is located **above**, FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data shows up.

*(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data)*

I tried to change `android:exported="false"` to `android:exported="true"` and didnt work. What else I can do?

*Any suggestions?*

> FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.android.boligchecker, PID: 488
>                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161)
>                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
>                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6;
>   regionStart=1; regionLength=-2
>                                                                                     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getFileForUri(FileProvider.java:734)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.query(FileProvider.java:435)
>                                                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1027)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:243)
>                                                                                     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:536)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompatJellybean.query(ContentResolverCompatJellybean.java:33)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat$ContentResolverCompatImplJB.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:57)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:125)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:59)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:37)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:302)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:45)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
>                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

Comment: That stack trace looks like it should have a "Caused by" part.

Answer (score 1):

> What else I can do?

Change one of the `android:authorities` values. Both have:

```
android:authorities="com.example.android.boligchecker"
```

That is not possible — there can only be one `ContentProvider` *on the device* with a given authority string.

So change one of the two to a different value.

Comment: Can I change with something random? I dont know where I can bring the word.

Comment: @panpanda: The authority names are whatever you want them to be. They just have to be unique.

Comment: I thought "android:authorities" match with something. By the way, after I change value of "android:authorities" of FileProvider, it gives me the error again with FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data.

Comment: @panpanda: "I thought "android:authorities" match with something" -- it has to match the `Uri` that you use to work with the provider. Since you control those `Uri` values, you have to change the authority string in both places.

Comment: I modified Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()) part to Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName() + ".something"). And com.example.android.boligchecker to  com.example.android.boligchecker.something. Now it works! Thank you! :)